# Texstudio: Put auxiliary files in a separate folder then PDFs

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, texstudio

I'm having a issue which is already been discussed here but apparently not with the solution I would like:

I'm using TexStudio and, while compiling, I would like to put auxiliary files in a different folder.
I'm following instruction and doing this (my folder is called tmp):

- Configure -> PdfLatex add: -output-directory tmp
- Configure -> Biber add: --output_directory tmp %
- Build -> Additional Search Path -> Log File add: .\tmp

and it works very well but also my pdfs are put into tmp folder and I would like to leave them in the same folder where .tex are.

May anyone help me, please?

Comment: You're confusing  `output-directory` and `aux-directory`.

Comment: And so, what should the command be?
Because if I write: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory=tmp %.tex I get this error message: "/usr/bin/pdflatex: unrecognized option '-aux-directory=tmp' "

Comment: For me it works with `pdflatex -synctex=1 --aux-directory=.TeXAux` (with a double hyphen at the beginning).

Comment: I still get this error "/usr/bin/pdflatex: unrecognized option '--aux-directory=.TeXAux' "
Is it possible I might install or add something else?
I'm using Ubuntu, maybe you need to know this

Comment: I am under Windows and MiKTeX, but as far as I know, what I posted uses a generic syntax.  Maybe trying looking at the details of TeX Live configuration.

Comment: I've seen that MikTex has this option unlike Texstudio. I don't understand whether Texstudio doesn't have it at all or just I don't know it

Comment: TeX studio is just an editor and MiKTeX  is a  TeX distribution. It can perfectly cooperate with MiKTeX as well as with TeX Live or MacTeX.

Comment: Oh ok, I see (I feel stupid now).
I'm seeing that MikTex is not installable on Ubuntu version over 18 (I have 19), so I still have problem. Damn

Comment: texlive has --output-directory not -aux-directory but generally I'd always advise against it, it is (at most) a cosmetic improvement and it vastly complicates the workflow, you move the aux and bbl files etc to a non standard place, then you have to configure _everything_ makeindex, bibtex, biber, tex, ... to find them. (@Bernard miktex has different option names here)